# VSCode clangd extension can not find header file

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang, clang++, clangd

My current file structure is:

```
├── common
│   └── example.cc
├── compile_commands.json
├── include
    └── common
        └── example.hh
```

`example.hh`: Leave it blank

`example.cc`:

```cpp
#include "common/example.hh"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

`compile_commands.json`:

```json
[
    {
        "directory": "/home/user/project",
        "file": "/home/user/project/common/example.cc",
        "arguments": [
            "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "-I /home/user/project/include",
            "-o example",
            "/home/user/project/common/example.cc"
        ],
        "output": "example"
    }
]
```

When opening `example.cc` it produces error:

```
'common/example.hh' file not found clang(pp_file_not_found)
```

I run the command directly and it works fine:

```sh
$ /usr/bin/clang++ -I /home/user/project/include -o example /home/user/project/common/example.cc
```

Environment info:

```
$ clang++ --version
clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

vscode: 1.47.3

vscode-clangd: 0.1.7

Comment: What's the result now?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in the `"arguments"` field of the `compile_commands.json` entry, `"-I /home/user/project/include"` is a single argument. (So is `"-o example"` though that doesn't cause any harm in this case.)

That means the command that's executed will be as if you had written:

```
$ /usr/bin/clang++ "-I /home/user/project/include" "-o example" /home/user/project/common/example.cc
```

(note the quotes around `"-I /home/user/project/include"` and `"-o example"`).

If you run that command, that gives the same `'common/example.hh' file not found clang(pp_file_not_found)` error. Basically, the quotes make clang think that the argument to `-I` starts with a space character, which then does not resolve as a path.

The solution is to place each token of the command line in a separate element of `"arguments"`:

```
[
    {
        "directory": "/home/user/project",
        "file": "/home/user/project/common/example.cc",
        "arguments": [
            "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "-I",
            "/home/user/project/include",
            "-o",
            "example",
            "/home/user/project/common/example.cc"
        ],
        "output": "example"
    }
]
```

---

The reason `"arguments"` is interpreted in this way is that the [format specification](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html) for `compile_commands.json` describes `"arguments"` as follows:

> arguments: The compile command argv as list of strings. This should run the compilation step for the translation unit `file`. `arguments[0]` should be the executable name, such as `clang++`. Arguments should not be escaped, but ready to pass to `execvp()`.

Basically, `"arguments"` are expected to be the command line arguments as a shell would parse them and pass them to the `argv` of a program. Since arguments are space-separated, the only way a single argument can contain an internal space is if that argument was quoted on the command line.

---

Finally, I'll note that `compile_commands.json` files are generally not meant to be written by hand, but instead generated by a tool (usually your project's build system or something related). See https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup for a list of commonly used tools to generate them.

If you *must* hand-write a `compile_commands.json`, it's probably easier to use `"command"` instead of `"arguments"` (refer to the [spec](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html#format) for an example), precisely to avoid issues like this.